# Analyze the regularity of the contour lines of the function $f(x,y,z) = ze^x+y\ln(x) - 3x\cos y -2$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

i need to study the regularity of the contour lines of this function $$f(x,y,z) = ze^x+y\ln(x) - 3x\cos y -2 \qquad with \ x>0;y,z\in \Bbb{R}$$

so i pose $f(x,y,z)=k $ with $k\in\Bbb{R}$
it gets me $$z=\frac{-y\ln x + 3x \cos y + 2 + k}{e^x}$$

from wich i get $$\nabla z = \left( \frac{-\frac{y}{x} +3\cos y +y\ln x -3x\cos y -2 -k}{e^x}, \frac{-\ln x -3x \sin y}{e^x}\right)$$
a curve is regular if its gradient exists and is non-zero,
the first condition is met everywhere in my domain the second is violated in $\nabla z = 0$ however this last equation gives me two equations in two variables (theoritically possible?? ) that is impossible to solve ( or at least very diffucult), i feel that i'm doing something wrong. Is there a better way? Thank you for your response

Comment: In the last line, are defining $\nabla z(x,y) = (\partial z(x, y)/\partial x, \partial z(x, y)/\partial y)$? Is this is the case then you made a mistake in calculating the derivative. For instance $$ \frac{\partial z(x, y)}{\partial y} = -3xe^{-x}\sin y $$

Comment: @caverac thank you, i wrote the function wrong in the post, ( it was ylnx not lnx) so i thank the derivatives are correct